# Too many PHP if/else statements for logged/not-logged-in users on web pages

Tags: php, html

So I have a lot of dynamic PHP webpages in my current project and am wondering how to deal with logged in/not logged in users. Various components throughout the pages are switched for logged in users. Some are entire divs, some just a couple words here and there. Some pages may ultimately have 10+ components like this.

I have previously read that having PHP sprinkled throughout a page can degrade performance, as well as echoing HTML in php, both of which are frequent in my project because of this issue.

I am wondering if there is some trick here to avoiding this?

Here is one example, which shows that some of the lengthiness of some embedded HTML scripts:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) and $_SESSION['sess_username'] != '') {
        echo '<div class="logged-user">';
        echo '<div class="btn-group">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
        echo '<img src="assets/img/user-avatar.png" alt="User Avatar" />';
        echo '<span class="name">' . $sess_username . '</span>';
        echo '<span class="caret"></span>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="#">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>';
        echo '<span class="text">Profile</span>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="#">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>';
        echo '<span class="text">Settings</span>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="#">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>';
        echo '<span class="text">Logout</span>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<p><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li></p>';

    }
?>
```

One option I thought of as far as performance would be essentially having code for two pages, and just running an if/else at the top of the page, and then direct the user to the proper page. This would avoid having as many if/else statements throughout the page, although it wouldn't necessarily reduce the amount of PHP sprinkled in the page.

Sincere thanks for any help!

Also, if anyone knows how to easily format code to pull-left in SO, I would love to know. I am sure it looks pretty crappy in my posts.

Comment: Sidenote: You can reduce a lot of the echoes by simply doing `echo '` (whole bunch of code) then finishing with `';`, or using [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: @ambe5950 to format the code to pull-left, highlight the code lines and click the `{ }` button on the text editor. Clicking it once will decrease the indentation of the highlighted code lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can just close the PHP tags like so:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) and $_SESSION['sess_username'] != ''): ?>

<div class="logged-user">
 .. more html ..
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do this for sure.

Comment: do you know if this is better than what the other responder suggested, "You can reduce a lot of the echoes by simply doing echo ' (whole bunch of code) then finishing with ';,"?

Comment: I would favor this version, as you don't need any echo at all. It also makes it impossible to hit syntax errors with punctuation this way :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to echo the html.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) and $_SESSION['sess_username'] != '') { ?>
        <div class="logged-user">
        <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img src="assets/img/user-avatar.png" alt="User Avatar" />
        <span class="name"><?php echo $sess_username;?></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <span class="text">Profile</span>
        </a>
        </li> ... </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php } else { ?>
        <p><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Second, if you have several pages with several content areas accessible only to logged in users, can you redesign the site and simply load a logged in version of the page with the proper components? Another option might be to set an html class as a variable.

Ex:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) and $_SESSION['sess_username'] != '') {
 //user is logged in, set authorized variable:
  $component_authorized = 'show';
    } else {
  $component_authorized = 'hide';
}
..
<div id="some_content">
<div id="everyone_see_content">...</div>
<div id="only_auth_user" class="<?php echo $component_authorized;?>"><!-- Auth User content --></div>
<div class="other_stuff">
     <!--everyone sees here-->
     <ul class="my_class <?php $component_authorized; ?>">
         <!-- Only Auth User Sees this list-->
     </ul>
</div>
```

Then just make sure your css has the .hide {display: none;}

The last recommendation is some java use which is a bit lengthy and unnecessary in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I love it. I will definitely incorporate that.